# Efficiently label points inside a bounding box

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a problem that I am trying to solve, have found a working code for, but it is extremely inefficient due to the amount of data I need to process. So here's a description of what I am trying to do:

I have a dataframe that contains bounding boxes around products on shelves. So every row contains information about the bounding boxe's boundaries, the camera that has taken the picture, the date and hour at which the picture was taken and I have calculated the bounding box center. One piece of info missing it which product it is (no id, no barcode).

```
index  boundingX0  boundingX1  boundingY0  boundingY1           cameraId  \
0      0      3167.0      3276.0      2532.0      2662.0  Z4301160003414164   
1      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164   
2      2      3278.0      3387.0      2532.0      2663.0  Z4301160003414164   
3      3      1264.0      1373.0       946.0      1097.0  Z4301160003414164   
4      4      1909.0      2002.0      1983.0      2151.0  Z4301160003414164   
5      5      1722.0      1808.0      1982.0      2150.0  Z4301160003414164   
6      6      3163.0      3281.0      2301.0      2460.0  Z4301160003414164   
7      7      2359.0      2469.0      2512.0      2629.0  Z4301160003414164   
8      8      1381.0      1496.0       947.0      1097.0  Z4301160003414164   
9      9      1053.0      1172.0      1958.0      2146.0  Z4301160003414164   

  filename        Date  Hour  facing_center_x  facing_center_y  
0        A  2022-05-17    13           3221.5           2597.0  
1        A  2022-05-17    13           1859.0           2068.5  
2        A  2022-05-17    13           3332.5           2597.5  
3        A  2022-05-17    13           1318.5           1021.5  
4        A  2022-05-17    13           1955.5           2067.0  
5        A  2022-05-17    13           1765.0           2066.0  
6        A  2022-05-17    13           3222.0           2380.5  
7        A  2022-05-17    13           2414.0           2570.5  
8        A  2022-05-17    13           1438.5           1022.0  
9        A  2022-05-17    13           1112.5           2052.0
```

I have however a second dataframe that contains the bounding boxes of the entire area in which a product is supposed to be and all the necessary information about the product (id, barcode) and information about camera, data, hour and so on.

```
index        Date           cameraId filename        itemId  \
0      0  2022-05-17  Z4301160003414164        A  5.903282e+07   
1      1  2022-05-17  Z4301160003414164        A  5.903282e+07   
2      2  2022-05-17  Z4301160003414164        A  8.013546e+07   
3      3  2022-05-17  Z4301160003414164        A  8.013546e+07   
4      4  2022-05-17  Z4301160003414164        A  3.760011e+10   
5      5  2022-05-17  Z4301160003414164        A  3.760011e+10   
6      6  2022-05-17  Z4301160003414164        A  3.017620e+12   
7      7  2022-05-17  Z4301160003414164        A  3.017620e+12   
8      8  2022-05-17  Z4301160003414164        A  3.017761e+12   
9      9  2022-05-17  Z4301160003414164        A  3.088541e+12   

             barcode       x       y  boundingX0  boundingX1  boundingY0  \
0  N4131466489013277  2117.0  1828.0      2117.0      3232.0      1540.0   
1  N4131466408713275  3233.0  1832.0      3233.0      3995.0      1540.0   
2  N4131466510613278  2905.0  1099.0      2905.0      4055.0       846.0   
3  N4131465123513276  2921.0   757.0      2921.0      4145.0       457.0   
4  N4131466272113278  1684.0   760.0      1684.0      2920.0       460.0   
5  N4131465122713277  1212.0   761.0      1212.0      1683.0       461.0   
6  N4131465130213271  2127.0  1461.0      2127.0      4013.0      1185.0   
7  N4131466226313279  2122.0  2158.0      2122.0      3981.0      1900.0   
8  N4141461925413272  4254.0  3081.0      4254.0      4598.0      2769.0   
9  N4131465932913278  1323.0  1817.0      1323.0      1478.0      1539.0   

   boundingY1  Hour  
0      1828.0    11  
1      1832.0    11  
2      1099.0    11  
3       757.0    11  
4       760.0    11  
5       761.0    11  
6      1461.0    11  
7      2158.0    11  
8      3081.0    11  
9      1817.0    11
```

What I want to do is to place the bounding box center in `facing` inside the product aread bounding box in `label`. If the center is in a given box, then append the barcode to the data in `facing`.

I have done this:

```
facing_index = list(set(facing.index))
label_index = list(set(label.index))

LABEL  =[]
for i in range(len(label_index)):
    f = label[label.index == i]
    cameraId = f.cameraId.iloc[0]
    date     = f.Date.iloc[0]
    hour     = f.Hour.iloc[0]
    for j in range(len(facing_index)):
        g = facing[(facing['cameraId']==cameraId) & (facing['Date']==date) & (facing['Hour']==hour)]
        points = [(g['facing_center_x'], g['facing_center_y'])]
        pts = np.array(points)
        ll = np.array([f['boundingX0'], f['boundingY0']])  # lower-left
        ur = np.array([f['boundingX1'], f['boundingY1']])  # upper-right
        inidx = np.all(np.logical_and(ll <= pts, pts <= ur), axis=1)
        inbox = pts[inidx]
        outbox = pts[np.logical_not(inidx)] 
        if len(inbox)>0:
            g['barcode']=f.barcode
        else:
            0
        LABEL.append(g)

LABEL = pd.concat(LABEL)
```

The problem is that this takes forever sice `label` contains over 125 000 rows and `facing` contains over 400 000 rows.

Another approach I tried was this: Defined the function

```
def BoundingBoxContains(rectangle,point):
    logic = rectangle[0] < point[0] < rectangle[0]+rectangle[2] and rectangle[1] < point[1] < rectangle[1]+rectangle[3]
    return logic
```

which checks if a point is in a rectangle. Then:

```
LABEL  =[]
for i in range(len(label_index)):
    f = label[label.index == i]
    BoundingBox   = (f.boundingX0[i],f.boundingX1[i],f.boundingY0[i],f.boundingY1[i])
    f = f.reset_index()
    date     = f.Date.iloc[0]
    filename     = f.filename.iloc[0]
    for j in range(len(facing_index)):
        g = facing[(facing['Date']==date) & (facing['filename']==filename)].reset_index()
        K = len(g)
        for k in range(K):
            gk = g[g.index==k]
            facingCenter = (gk['facing_center_x'][k], gk['facing_center_y'][k])
            a = rectContains(BoundingBox, facingCenter)
            if a == True:
                gk['barcode'] = f.barcode
            else:
                0

            LABEL.append(gk)
```

which gives:

```
   level_0  index  boundingX0  boundingX1  boundingY0  boundingY1  \
0        0      0      3167.0      3276.0      2532.0      2662.0   
0        0      0      3167.0      3276.0      2532.0      2662.0   
0        0      0      3167.0      3276.0      2532.0      2662.0   
0        0      0      3167.0      3276.0      2532.0      2662.0   
0        0      0      3167.0      3276.0      2532.0      2662.0   
0        0      0      3167.0      3276.0      2532.0      2662.0   
0        0      0      3167.0      3276.0      2532.0      2662.0   
0        0      0      3167.0      3276.0      2532.0      2662.0   
0        0      0      3167.0      3276.0      2532.0      2662.0   
0        0      0      3167.0      3276.0      2532.0      2662.0   

            cameraId filename        Date  Hour  facing_center_x  \
0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    13           3221.5   
0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    13           3221.5   
0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    13           3221.5   
0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    13           3221.5   
0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    13           3221.5   
0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    13           3221.5   
0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    13           3221.5   
0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    13           3221.5   
0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    13           3221.5   
0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    13           3221.5   

   facing_center_y            barcode  
0           2597.0  N4131465122613276  
0           2597.0  N4131465122613276  
0           2597.0  N4131465122613276  
0           2597.0  N4131465122613276  
0           2597.0  N4131465122613276  
0           2597.0  N4131465122613276  
0           2597.0  N4131465122613276  
0           2597.0  N4131465122613276  
0           2597.0  N4131465122613276  
0           2597.0  N4131465122613276
```

I haven't been able to find a more efficient way to do so and would be very grateful for any insights.

Comment: Why do you have the inner loop `for j in range(len(facing_index)):` ?

Comment: Because there are multiple cameras and I want the check of a point being in a bounding box to be for the right picture. If I didn't have the loop, it would check if a point is in a bounding box in a different part of the shelf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, I think you should merge `facing` and `label` dataframes on `Date`, `Hour` and `cameraId` columns first then apply your `BoundingBoxContains` function.

If you have enough memory use `merge` without any caution. The `apply` part is just a loop on each row. This part can be really optimized by using `multiprocessing`. If the first part succeeds, I can propose you an implementation of MP with `multiprocessing.Pool`.

Now the code:

```
def BoundingBoxContains(rectangle, point):
    logic = rectangle[0] < point[0] < rectangle[0]+rectangle[2] and rectangle[1] < point[1] < rectangle[1]+rectangle[3]
    return logic

bbox_contains = lambda x: BoundingBoxContains((x.boundingX0, x.boundingX1, x.boundingY0, x.boundingY1),
                                              (x.facing_center_x, x.facing_center_y))

cols = ['Date', 'Hour', 'cameraId', 'barcode']
out = facing.merge(label[cols], on=cols[:-1])
out = out.loc[out.apply(bbox_contains, axis=1)]
```

Notes: I have to modify `Hour` (13 -> 11) to have match.

Can you explain?

```
facing_index = list(set(facing.index))
label_index = list(set(label.index))
```

Output:

```
>>> out.drop_duplicates(cols)  # if you want to keep only one instance per cols
    index  boundingX0  boundingX1  boundingY0  boundingY1           cameraId filename        Date  Hour  facing_center_x  facing_center_y            barcode
10      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    11           1859.0           2068.5  N4131466489013277
11      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    11           1859.0           2068.5  N4131466408713275
12      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    11           1859.0           2068.5  N4131466510613278
13      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    11           1859.0           2068.5  N4131465123513276
14      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    11           1859.0           2068.5  N4131466272113278
15      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    11           1859.0           2068.5  N4131465122713277
16      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    11           1859.0           2068.5  N4131465130213271
17      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    11           1859.0           2068.5  N4131466226313279
18      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    11           1859.0           2068.5  N4141461925413272
19      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164        A  2022-05-17    11           1859.0           2068.5  N4131465932913278
```

**Update 1**

Do you have enough memory to create this dataframe on GCP?

```
cam_cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(np.unique([facing['cameraId'].unique(), 
                                         label['cameraId'].unique()]))

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': pd.to_datetime(facing['Date'] + ' ' + facing['Hour'].astype(str)),
    'cameraId': facing['cameraId'].astype(cam_cat),
    'facing': facing['index']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': pd.to_datetime(label['Date'] + ' ' + label['Hour'].astype(str)),
    'cameraId': label['cameraId'].astype(cam_cat),
    'label': label['index']
})

# Lighweight merge to use with multiprocessing
dfm = df1.merge(df2, on=['DateTime', 'cameraId'])
```

**Update 2**

Before using `multiprocessing` can you check the output of `dfm` after the 2-pass filtering:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Vectorized function
def BoundingBoxContains(df):
    m1 = df['facing_center_x'].between(df['boundingX0'], df['boundingX0'] + df['boundingY0'])
    m2 = df['facing_center_y'].between(df['boundingX1'], df['boundingX1'] + df['boundingY1'])
    return m1 & m2


# Your load routine
facing = pd.read_csv('facing.csv')
label = pd.read_csv('label.csv')

# Create a category dtype from cameraId to reduce memory footprint
cam_cat = pd.CategoricalDtype(np.unique([facing['cameraId'].unique(),
                                         label['cameraId'].unique()]))

# Extract real index (not 'index' column) from each dataframes
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': pd.to_datetime(facing['Date'] + ' ' + facing['Hour'].astype(str)),
    'cameraId': facing['cameraId'].astype(cam_cat),
    'facing': facing.index
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'DateTime': pd.to_datetime(label['Date'] + ' ' + label['Hour'].astype(str)),
    'cameraId': label['cameraId'].astype(cam_cat),
    'label': label.index
})

# 1st pass: lookup on DateTime and cameraId to keep only possible match
# Cross product of facing / label with valid DateTime / cameraId
dfm = df1.merge(df2, on=['DateTime', 'cameraId'])

CHUNKSIZE = 10  # Chuncksize
facing_cols = ['facing_center_x', 'facing_center_y']
label_cols = ['boundingX0', 'boundingX1', 'boundingY0', 'boundingY1', 'barcode']

# 2nd pass: match facing coords on bounding box
# Filter out the dataframe
mask = []
for i in range(0, len(dfm), CHUNKSIZE):
    F = facing.loc[dfm.iloc[i:i+CHUNKSIZE]['facing'], facing_cols].reset_index(drop=True)
    L = label.loc[dfm.iloc[i:i+CHUNKSIZE]['label'], label_cols].reset_index(drop=True)
    mask.append(BoundingBoxContains(pd.concat([F, L], axis=1)))
dfm = dfm.loc[pd.concat(mask, ignore_index=True)]
```

Output:

```
>>> dfm
              DateTime           cameraId  facing  label
19 2022-05-17 11:00:00  Z4301160003414164       1      9
49 2022-05-17 11:00:00  Z4301160003414164       4      9
59 2022-05-17 11:00:00  Z4301160003414164       5      9
79 2022-05-17 11:00:00  Z4301160003414164       7      9
```

**Update 3**

The last step is to reconstruct a dataframe from `facing` and `label` columns of `dfm`:

```
out = facing.loc[dfm['facing']].assign(barcode=label.loc[dfm['label'], 'barcode'].values)
print(out)

# Output
   index  boundingX0  boundingX1  boundingY0  boundingY1           cameraId  \
1      1      1812.0      1906.0      1985.0      2152.0  Z4301160003414164   
4      4      1909.0      2002.0      1983.0      2151.0  Z4301160003414164   
5      5      1722.0      1808.0      1982.0      2150.0  Z4301160003414164   
7      7      2359.0      2469.0      2512.0      2629.0  Z4301160003414164   

  filename        Date  Hour  facing_center_x  facing_center_y  \
1        A  2022-05-17    11           1859.0           2068.5   
4        A  2022-05-17    11           1955.5           2067.0   
5        A  2022-05-17    11           1765.0           2066.0   
7        A  2022-05-17    11           2414.0           2570.5   

             barcode  
1  N4131465932913278  
4  N4131465932913278  
5  N4131465932913278  
7  N4131465932913278
```

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for and it work well but there is not enough memory, en when running on GCP. I've tried a few things with ```multiprocessing.Pool``` but with no luck. I essentially tried to define your code as a function of two dataframes (replacing the facing and label) and by creating splits of facing anf label into smaller dataframes but there is an issue in matching. Any ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check if you have enough memory to load the update on GCP, please?

Comment: It worked perfectly well and fast.

Comment: Your problem is not so obvious :) I updated my answer by a little step Can you the check the output of `dfm`, please?

Comment: I get this error: ```KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Int64Index([133263, 133265, 133267, 133268, 133270,\n            ...\n            133332, 133335, 133336, 133338, 133340],\n           dtype='int64', length=923). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike"``` at ```L = ESL_areas.loc[dfm.iloc[i:i+CHUNKSIZE]['label'], label_cols].reset_index()```. Going to check why.

Comment: Works now. Just an issue with indexing. Is also very fast with the full dataframes.

Comment: Do you mean you don't need the loop?

Comment: I mean that what you provided works really well. So, I guess the next step is to marh dtm to both facing and labil?

Comment: You are right about the next step :) `out = facing.loc[dfm['facing']].assign(barcode=label.loc[dfm['label'], 'barcode'].values)`. Let me know if it's what you expect.

Comment: Un grand merci pour cette excellente réponse !